# Long file path returning 404 for "hello.htm"

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404, path

I have a long file path that works on my server, but a simliar path returns a 404 error when it is on my clients (IIS6) server (http://ddmat.com/).

Here's the functioning file path on my server:
http://www.forgefx.com/projects/ddmat/install/Application Files/McCurdys_1_0_0_0/Content/FBX/CCAE1B33/Roof-sectionB-02.fbm/hello.htm

My guesses:

1. Maybe the file path is too long?
2. Maybe the ".fbm" in the directory path is invalid?

Sorry for the vauge problem description.  Please let me know what additional info I can provide that'd be helpful.

Update:
The problem happens even in short paths, with no spaces:
http://www.myserver/test.folder/hell.htm

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in finding out the cause of this also. So I did some research online. I found this article. I think it might help answering this issue.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315122

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space in "Application Files". You should URL-encode the link (substitute the space with %20 in this case):

http://www.forgefx.com/projects/ddmat/install/Application%20Files/McCurdys_1_0_0_0/Content/FBX/CCAE1B33/Roof-sectionB-02.fbm/hello.htm

**Update:**

Two things:

1. Perhaps your client forgot to install/enable static content on IIS. It's a feature that must be explicitly enabled on the server. See this blog post: [Don't forget to check "Static content service" in IIS7 installation](http://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/archive/2008/05/23/don-t-forget-to-check-quot-static-content-service-quot-in-iis7-installation.aspx) (it's Vista related: here the Windows Server 2008 procedure: http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-iis7 )

[image: IIS check static content feature IIS 7]

2. It would be very strange, because it's not the default for `.htm`, but maybe your client's IIS/website configuration doesn't allow the `htm` mimetype. See this support article: [IIS 6.0 does not serve unknown MIME types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326965)